# Materials + Cycles = high-def image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am using Blender 2.8 and Cycles. When I zoom in on the 3D meshes in my scene, I can get very clear closeups.

When I render (using Denoising, 1200 samples, 1920x1080), zooming in on the resulting image shows smaller meshes in the scene as blurry. I worked hard to achieve a realistic look with many smaller meshes, so I want to be able to see them close-up in the rendered image.

If I do not care much about rendering times (that is, less than 2 days; preferably less than 1 day), is there a way to render a highly-detailed image of my scene? If so, how?

Thank you,
edsager

Comment: Perhaps it's because of the focus point of your camera?

Comment: Probably the resolution. 1920*1080 is enough to cover a screen but it's not enough to zoom into. Try doubling or quadrupling the resolution. Also, throttle back the denoising a bit if you're willing to do a lot of samples, as that will lose small details.

Comment: If there is something small and detail in your render, i will personally use a **render cropping** to render higher resolution on those part and combine them

Comment: @Hikariztw: When say you combine "them" are you talking about combining the cropped render to a different, lesser resolution render? Do you use software like Photoshop to do the combining? Are you able to combine the cropped and other render with precision?

Comment: @Joseph Brandenburg: I am using as the resolution 7680x4320, I eliminated Denoising, and have used 8000 samples. It appears that this rendering will likely meet my needs and the estimated rendering time is 38 hours. It has been rendering for more than 16 hours currently. I am amazed at the stability of Blender 2.8.

Comment: The answer by @Joseph Brandenburg was the most helpful, but I am not certain how to mark his response as the answer. Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: Don't worry about it, mine was a comment. It's hard to be sure whether to comment or answer properly since a lot of the questions on this forum require clarification.